# How to specify module implementation at compile time in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have an application that should support multiple types of storages. At the moment, I want it to support both S3 and swift.

**Now for the question:** How do I allow for my application to choose which backend it will use at the load time (as in, the config will specify whether it will be S3 or swift)?

In OOP I would have interface, and could inject a dependency. In this case, the obvious answer was GenServer. But I don't actually need a whole dedicated process (which should also act as a chokepoint for my code).

I considered simply passing the reference to a module as a parameter, but it feels kinda iffy, since technically an incorrect implementation could be passed.

**Thus to further specify:** How do I go about injecting a specific backend (S3 or swift) into my code based on config (**without Genserver**)?

```
defmodule App.Filestorage do
    @callback store(String.t) :: :ok | :error
end

defmodule App.S3 do
    @behaviour App.Filestorage
    @impl
    def store(path), do: :ok 
end

defmodule App.Swift do
    @behaviour App.Filestorage
    @impl
    def store(path), do: :ok
end

defmodule App.Foo do
    def do_stuff()
        # doing some stuff
        App.Filestorage.store(result_file) # replace this with S3 or Swift
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way!
To use injections by configs, you could specify name of the selected executable module and get its name from config to call it:

```
config:
config :app, :filestorage, App.S3


defmodule App.Filestorage.Behaviour do
    @callback store(String.t) :: :ok | :error
end

defmodule App.Filestorage do
  def adapter(), do: Application.get_env(:app, :filestorage)
  def store(string), to: adapter().store
end

defmodule App.S3 do
    @behaviour App.Filestorage.Behaviour
    @impl true
    def store(path), do: :ok 
end

defmodule App.Swift do
    @behaviour App.Filestorage.Behaviour
    @impl true
    def store(path), do: :ok
end

defmodule App.Foo do
    def do_stuff()
        # doing some stuff
        App.Filestorage.store(result_file) # replace this with S3 or Swift
    end
end
```

*NOTE 1: You could merge behaviour(App.Filestorage.Behaviour) and "implemention"(App.Filestorage) modules if you want*

*NOTE 2: You could use a module attribute to specify the adapter from config, but be aware of side effects during deploy, because it will save the exact config that would be during compile time*

*NOTE 3: If you use adapter specification by function, same as is it in the example, you could even change the selected implementation during runtime, by changing config*

More details at the posts:
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/
https://blog.carbonfive.com/lightweight-dependency-injection-in-elixir-without-the-tears/

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting solution. Though a question, just to understand correctly,- this sacrifices the type safety, no? As in, an incorrect module can be injected in config.

Comment: Consire config as a part of the code base - if you somehow set wrong module which has same functions - it would be the same error as if you use wrong module directly in the code. If you mean injection by user input - it cannot happen